# Process starts from inittab but stops by itself at the same time

Tags: debian, init.d

I have installed pyload in my My Book World Edition and I would like to make it boot everytime I boot up the drive. I wrote the line below in "inittab"

```
::respawn:/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py
```

My problem is that although pyload loads, which means the entry is recognized in "inittab", it stops automatically after. An then it reloads and restops again (due to the "respawn" command)

```
daemon.info init: Starting pid 4298, console /dev/ttyS0: '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py'
daemon.info init: Process '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py' (pid 4298) exited.  Scheduling it for restart.
daemon.info init: Starting pid 4320, console /dev/ttyS0: '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py'
daemon.info init: Process '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py' (pid 4320) exited.  Scheduling it for restart.
daemon.info init: Starting pid 4321, console /dev/ttyS0: '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py'
daemon.info init: Process '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py' (pid 4321) exited.  Scheduling it for restart.
daemon.info init: Starting pid 4322, console /dev/ttyS0: '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py'
daemon.info init: Process '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py' (pid 4322) exited.  Scheduling it for restart.
```

Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: *"anybody know why is this happening?"*  Why don't you throw some logging into `pyLoadCore.py` to find out?

Comment: The "dumb" question: does the command `/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py` work?  Even if you aren't in that directory when you run it?

Comment: @goldilocks Since is start and stops at the same time, is doesn't actually starts, so there is nothing written in the log.

Comment: @Scott yes it does work. I have double checked it.

Comment: Try putting `sh -c '/opt/share/pyload/pyLoadCore.py >> /some/log.file 2>&1'` into "inittab".  Or, perhaps, a `pyLoadCore.sh` script that would do that.

Comment: @Scott Thank you very much for you help. With the "sh ..."  line you wrote me, I found that it could not load python (wrong folder). Everything is OK now. Many thanks